# How to host Laravel 9 on cPanel's subfolder correctly without requiring to add '/public'?

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I have a project called `projectX` and I have deployed that on cPanel's subfolder / sub directory. Everything is working fine except the user has to go to `https://example.com/demo/projectX/public` but it should work `https://example.com/demo/projectX` alone without adding `public` to it.

I have tried redirecting the subfolder to subfolder/public on cPanel with its default `Redirects` option and tried many code snippets for .htaccess found on stackoverflow discussions and other sources but still not working. It works only if there is `public` after the `subfolder`.

Working link: `https://example.com/demo/projectX/public`
How it should work: `https://example.com/demo/projectX`

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to put your files in a subfolder/subdirectory?

In cPanel's file manager, you will see the `public_html` what you need to do is put your projectX folder there, and after that create a new file **inside** your projectX folder and name it `.htaccess`, the content of that file as follows...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The final folder structure should be:

`\public_html\projectX\.htaccess`

Comment: Hi @Lucky Person, the domain and hosting are ours but the project is for the client. We have a demo directory under our domain where we put all our clients' websites and show them as a demo link before website is final. Only when it's final, we migrate the website under demo directory to client's main domain. Static websites, wordpress and codeigniter projects are already there and working fine. We just started a new project for our client and it's in laravel. So, we are now finding a way to make Laravel project works like others on sub directory / subfolder.

Comment: let's say you have your company folder named `company` and inside that is the `projectX` folder? then all you need to do is, put the `.htaccess` inside the `projectX` folder, try it and update me again.

Comment: It just redirects me to 404 page when visiting to the url without /public after submitting the .htaccess file with the codes you mentioned.

Comment: I think the issue is the top-level folder (company folder), is it WordPress?